# problems with implementing deque with templates

Tags: c++, templates

Recently I have tried to implement sequel using templates. Here is result

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename Type>
struct Node {
    Node();
    Node<Type>* next = NULL;
    Node<Type>* prev = NULL;
    Type data;
};

template<typename Type>
class deque{
 private:
     Node<Type>* front = NULL;
     Node<Type>* back = NULL;

 public:
     deque(Type key);
     ~deque();
     Node<Type>* back();
     Node<Type>* front();
     int size();
     bool empty();
     void push_front(Type key);
     void push_back(Type key);
     void pop_front();
     void pop_back();
     void print_in_order();
};


 template<typename Type>
  deque<Type>::deque(Type key)
{
     if (front != NULL || back != NULL)
         return
     else
     {
         front = new Node<Type>();
         front->data = key;
         prev = front;
     }
}

 template<typename Type>
  deque<Type>::~deque()
{
     Node<Type>* delPtr;
     while (front->prev != NULL)
    {
         delPtr = front;
         cout << "Deleted " << front->data<<endl;
         front = front->prev;
         delete delPtr;

    }
     back = NULL;
     delete front;
}

 template<typename Type>
  Node<Type>* deque<Type>::back()
{
      if(back!= NULL)
         return back;
     else 
          return NULL
}

 template<class Type>
  Node<Type>* deque<Type>::front()
{
     return front;
}

 template<typename Type>
  int deque<Type>::size()
{
     int counter = 0;
     Node<Type>* temp = front;
     while (temp->back != NULL)
    {
         counter++;
         temp = temp->back;
    }
     return counter;
}

 template<typename Type>
  bool deque<Type>::empty()
{
     if (front == NULL && back == NULL)
         return true;
     else
         return false;
}

 template<typename Type>
  void deque<Type>::push_front(Type key)
{
     Node<Type>* temp = new Node<Type>();
     temp->data = key;
     temp->prev = front;
     front->next = temp;
     front = temp;
}

 template<typename Type>
  void deque<Type>::push_back(Type key)
{
     Node<Type>* temp = new Node<Type>();
     temp->data = key;
     temp->next = back;
     back->prev = temp;
     back = temp;
}

 template<typename Type>
 inline void deque<Type>::pop_front()
{
     if (front != NULL) {
         Node<Type>* delPtr = front;
         front = front->prev;
         front->next = NULL;
         delete delPtr;
    }
     else
         cout << "There is no front in empty deque" << endl;
}

 template<typename Type>
  void deque<Type>::pop_back()
{
     if (back != NULL) {
         Node<Type>* delPtr = back;
         back = back->next;
         back->prev = NULL;
         delete delPtr;
    }
     else
         cout << "There is no back in empty deque " << endl;
}

 template<typename Type>
  void deque<Type>::print_in_order()
{
     if (front == NULL)
         return;
     Node<Type> temp = front;
     while (temp->prev != NULL) {
         cout << temp->data << " ";
         temp = temp->prev;
    }
     cout << endl;
}

 template<typename Type>
 inline Node<Type>::Node()
{
}
```

Then some code to check whether it is working

```
int main(){
    deque<int> qq(1);
    qq.push_front(2);
    qq.push_front(3);
    qq.print_in_order();
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't want to compile. I have tried looking for similar project or bugs and couldn't find anything useful. Therefore it would be great if someone could explain what is going wrong.
Most of errors are the same. For instance it is not allowed to use `back()` or `front()` because they are not functions and not a static members. Or `back()` and `front()` as members of template of class can't receive type of function. Hope someone can help.

Comment: "This code doesn't want to compile" - please include the errors. Also - this is **far** from *Minimal* example

Comment: Btw - even without the errors I can see that you have duplicate declarations... in `private` you have `Node<Type>* front`, which is a pointer, and in `public` you have a method called `front` You cannot have duplicate names without dealing with overloading, which in this case, you are not

Comment: This is a doubly linked list. When you insert a new node into a doubly link list, you have 4 links to update. You only update 2. Additionally, your front and back pointers never seem to refer to the same linked list.

Comment: `Node<Type> temp = front;` front is a pointer, what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a conflict between

```
Node<Type>* front = NULL;
Node<Type>* back = NULL;
```

and

```
Node<Type>* back();
Node<Type>* front();
```

So first of all change `Node<Type>* front = NULL;` to `Node<Type>* m_front = NULL;` and the same to `back`. There are another errors on your code, for example

```
Node<Type> temp = front;
```

have to be

```
Node<Type>* temp = front;
```

Finally, you can see the code without compilation errors on [ideone](https://ideone.com/4szLYT)

Good Lucky!